# Open chrome book default video player programmatically

Tags: google-chrome-app

I want to open the video player from my application to play a video. The video is selected by my application.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Assuming `google-chrome-app` tag means a [packaged chrome app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html), you can't do that because new apps can run only in ChromeOS and ChromeOS doesn't support nativeMessaging API. Chrome [extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions.html) on the other hand can use [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging.html) API to launch a separate utility that can run the video player.